# My Excel VBA DateDiff calculation is truncating answer. How do I get more precise answer?

Tags: excel, vba, datediff

I am trying to calculate a date difference in weeks.  I would actually like an answer to the nearest 10th decimal place (0.0).  The calculation is truncating or rounding my result.  How do I get a more precise answer?  Code below

```
Option Explicit


Sub DateTesting()

Dim Date1 As Date

Dim Date2 As Date

Dim DaysDiffer As Long

Dim WeeksDiffer As Long



Date1 = "1/10/2021"

Date2 = "7/14/2021"


DaysDiffer = DateDiff("d", Date1, Date2)

MsgBox DaysDiffer               

'185 is the result


WeeksDiffer = DaysDiffer / 7        

' 185/7= 26.4285


MsgBox WeeksDiffer      

' 26 is the result

'  Why am I getting a truncated integer value for the calculation of Weeks???

End Sub
```

Comment: Try `Dim WeeksDiffer As Double` [Double data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/double-data-type)

Comment: Because a date variable holds a date AND a time. The numbers to the right of the decimal represent the time. Since you defined `WeeksDiffer` as a `Long`, it rounds to the nearest integer/long value, removing the time part of it.

Comment: Also, `DateDiff` returns a variant (Long) - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/datediff-function

Comment: Instead, get the number of seconds `SecsDiffer = DateDiff("s", Date1, Date2)` and then do the math to get the decimal part of the value.

Comment: Note that `"1/10/2021"` is not a date it is a string (text). If you put this into a variable of type `Date` Excel tries to convert it into a numeric date. Here Excel needs to decide if the date is `mm/dd/yyyy` or `dd/mm/yyyy` and it does this by using the date format that is set in Windows. So that means the results can be different on different systems. Never let Excel interpret strings and convert them into date. I recommend always to use `DateSerial(year, month, day)` to create a real numeric date.

Comment: Thank you so much!  Changing the data type to Double worked perfectly!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to obtain your *rounded decimal weeks*:

```vb
Sub DateTesting()

    Dim Date1       As Date
    Dim Date2       As Date

    Dim DaysDiffer  As Long
    Dim WeeksDiffer As Double

    Date1 = #1/10/2021#
    Date2 = #7/14/2021#

    DaysDiffer = DateDiff("d", Date1, Date2)

    MsgBox DaysDiffer               
    ' 185 is the result

    WeeksDiffer = DaysDiffer / 7        
    ' 26.4285714285714 is the result

    MsgBox Format(WeeksDiffer, "0.0")
    ' 26.4 is the rounded result

End Sub
```

For all sorts of date handling, see [VBA.Date](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Date).

For high precision rounding, see [VBA.Round](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Round).

Comment: Thank you so much! Changing the data type to Double worked perfectly!!